# Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'http' in 'package:http/http.dart'.

Comment: Hey and welcome to Stackoverflow. You're asking why you're getting an error? Well, for us to find out you need to put some effort into your question. for example What code part produces this error (so put code snippets), What are you trying to do? How are you trying to achieve something and why? The most important thing right now is that you post your code, **but not everything. just as much so we can identify your error**. Have a good time on this platform :)

Answer (score 6):

It's because you have incorrectly placing your dependencies in your pubspec.yaml, something like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    http: ^0.12.0+2
```

which means `http` is the part of the `flutter` key.

You need to remove the space and give an extra new line to make it correct, something like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

Seet the YAML Basics description from https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

Comment: You the real hero! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the .yaml file indentation is important.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

This is a tree like structure which IDE used to read. Inside the **flutter** package there is a sub package called **sdk**. If something belongs to flutter then is should be added under the *flutter:*.

In your case, **http** is a different package which doesn't belongs to **flutter** dependency. So it will results error. Since http is a different dependency it needs to be added as a new dependency like above.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put http: ^ 0.12.0 + 2 above futter

so instead of

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

do that:

```
dependencies:
 http: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```